# Offline mode for Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using own offline tiles and Google Maps SDK to display it in offline mode. Is any possibility to set Google Maps in offline mode?

I have a problem that Google Maps doesn't display my own tiles when a internet connection is bad because Google Maps try to get some certification from Google servers.

When you set in Network Link Conditioner - 100% lost, your own tiles doesn't work with Google Maps SDK. In airplane mode everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used 2nd tile which required access to the internet. Google maps always wait for the both layers before display it.